# OpenStack Horizon dashboard (Folsom release) js builder

Tags: javascript, openstack, openstack-horizon

As I know, OpenStack Horizon dashboard (Folsom release) uses [LESS.js](http://lesscss.org/) to compile *.css static files. That's clear.

But I can't figure out what is used to compress Horizon *.js files (such as *horizon.instances.js*, etc.) to smth like *176baabe0b2d.js*, which directly works in browser.

Need your help to determine this js builder. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was found.

There is a `COMPRESS_OFFLINE` constant in `../openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py` file. It should be equal to `True`.

Then you should run `./manage.py compress` command from your `../openstack_dashboard` directory to rebuild compressed js Horizon files.

Comment: hii Julia. I'm beginner in django and i'm customizing openstack horizon. i guess you've did this job. can you help me in this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954229/how-to-render-datatable-inside-ajax-modal-in-openstack-horizon-dashboard
or please suggest some good articles and your experience if you've written in ur blog..  Thanx in Advance :)